# Can we use Swipe / Touch events in LWC mobile

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html5, css3

A very happy new year to all of u .
I am trying to built a swipe/ touch feature using lwc for mobile version  like below

[image]

I have reached till this point where i am able to swipe it, but after releasing the touch , the  is again back to its original place. Basically after swipe it should stay and then i should be able to click in delete or edit . Can anyone help me out . Let me know if the question/ problem statement is not clear

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/7ZwI9ihgjKt9sbgKFfCP/src/app.html?p=stories

Comment: if the swipe event is "triggering" an onload event, and your page is reloaded, it is normal behavior. You will most likely need to store the state of your app somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LWC, you're not allowed to use innerHTML, except in some cases, and document.querySelector will have unexpected behavior.

Here's the [minimum modifications](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/RfAwZ6opzvu3XPjH5fBT/src/app.html?p=stories) to make your code work:

```
<template>
    <div class="swipe-container" ontouchend={handleSwipe}>
        <!-- left action -->
        <div class="action left">
            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </div>
        <!-- swipeable element -->
        <div class="swipe-element">
            Swipe me to the left or right
        </div>
        <!-- right action -->
        <div class="action right">
            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- debug output -->
    <p class="output">{message}</p>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  message;

handleSwipe() {
  // define the minimum distance to trigger the action
  const minDistance = 80;
  const container = this.template.querySelector('.swipe-container');
  const output = this.template.querySelector('.output');
  // get the distance the user swiped
  console.log(container.scrollLeft)
  const swipeDistance = container.scrollLeft - container.clientWidth;
  if (swipeDistance < minDistance * -1) {
    this.message = 'swiped left';
  } else if (swipeDistance > minDistance) {
    this.message = 'swiped right';
  } else {
    this.message = `did not swipe ${minDistance}px`;
  }
}
}
```

Notice how we use a class variable `message` to display the output message, and we use `this.template.querySelector` instead of `document.querySelector`.

Note that whatever code sample you got this from apparently doesn't support a "confirm" mode, where you expose the action then click on a button. If you swipe far enough to perform the action (e.g. 80px), it is meant to perform the action immediately, which is a Google Material Design pattern.